# Octobercms relation [1,3,4,5] query in frontend model

Tags: jquery, json, filter, model, octobercms

i have model **Gallery** with relation ( builder plugin )

```
/* Relations */

 public $hasMany = [

    'category_name' => [
                        'aapaaa\webcontent\models\Category',
                        'table' => 'aapa_webcontent_category',
                        'key' => 'id',
                        'otherKey' => 'activity'
            ]  

];
```

in the table in the filed **activity** ( protected $jsonable ) i have stored for example values **[1,3,4,5]** ( category's id )

how can i filter records for example for values **1 and 3** ?

```
$records = Gallery::where( 'activity', [1,3]... ????





DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery`;

CREATE TABLE `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `aktivity` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `enable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vaha` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOCK TABLES `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` (`id`, `title`, `slug`, `description`, `aktivity`, `enable`, `vaha`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`)
VALUES
    (14,'TARGET PICTURES PRODUCTION','target-pictures-production',NULL,'[2]',1,14,'2021-11-12 21:51:11','2021-11-12 21:51:11',NULL),
    (1256,'ARMADA FILMS','armada-films',NULL,'[2,3,5]',1,1256,'2021-11-12 21:51:11','2021-11-12 21:51:11',NULL),
    (1265,'DAWSON PRODUCTIONS','dawson-productions',NULL,'[1,2,3,5]',1,1265,'2021-11-12 21:51:11','2021-11-12 21:51:11',NULL),
    (1270,'GOLDEN DAWN','golden-dawn',NULL,'[1,3,5]',1,1270,'2021-11-12 21:51:11','2021-11-12 21:51:11',NULL),
    (1278,'LUXOR','luxor',NULL,'[1,2,3,5]',1,1278,'2021-11-12 21:51:11','2021-11-12 21:51:11',NULL);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

thank you for your help

Vasek

Comment: you can check Laravel docus for that you can use like `$records = Gallery::whereJsonContains('activity', [1, 3]))` . link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: yes i tried this before ask..

$_records = Gallery::whereJsonContains('activity', [1, 3])->get();

but it fail..

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'json_contains' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery` where `json_contains` = activity and `apaaaa_webcontent_gallery`.`deleted_at` is null order by `vaha` asc)") in...

Comment: which version you are using of OctoberCMS

Comment: I have version 1 build 473

Comment: can you check this one https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#json-where-clauses, as laravel 5.5 is used, this should help you

Comment: can you please share `activity` column schema and demo data what is inside it

Comment: Thank you, i was add column schema and demo data to question